# Box2D compiling trouble. nullptr

Tags: c++, linux, box2d, nullptr

guys.
I am compiling Box2D from the source code, and give some trouble.
I ran lash version of premake in Box2D directory, then I switched to /Build/gmake and ran make.
Make return me this:

```
../../Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.cpp: In member function ‘void b2Body::DestroyFixture(b2Fixture*)’:
../../Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.cpp:216:17: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
if (fixture == nullptr)
               ^
```

Can enyone help me? I use Ubuntu Linux 14.04.

Comment: what version of gcc do you have installed?

Comment: @slf I use gcc 4.8.4

Comment: @slf I solve my problem by add -std=gnu++0x to makefile, generated by premake

Answer (score 0):

> I solve my problem by add -std=gnu++0x to makefile, generated by premake

Answer (score 0):

The premake file (premake5.lua) mentions C++11 with this snippet:

```
filter { "language:C++", "toolset:gcc" }
    buildoptions { "-std=c++11" }
```

does it doesn't seem to work. This is probably related to [this issue](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/issues/770), whose solution is to use `cppdialect` which is only available from premake 5 alpha 12 (at the time of writing, last release is alpha 11, which means you need to download the latest version directly on GitHub).

As a quick fix, you can follow the OP's own answer: modify the Make files of Box2D (also HelloWorld and Testbed if needed) by adding `-std=c++11` (resp. `gnu++11`, `c++14`, etc.) to `ALL_CXXFLAGS`.

If you prefer modifying the premake itself:

1. In **premake5.lua**, Comment out the filter / buildoptions snippet mentioned above
2. In projects Box2D (also HelloWorld and Testbed if needed), add `flags "C++11"` (you can also add `buildoptions { "-std=c++11" }`, the only difference is that it will also add the option to ALL_CFLAGS)

Example:

```
project "Box2D"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C++"
    flags "C++11"  -- added
    files { "Box2D/**.h", "Box2D/**.cpp" }
    includedirs { "." }
```

I intend to send a PR to Box2D's repository with this change.

EDIT: Done, here is the [PR](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/pull/469).